# How can I create test class to use the hyperlink field?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests, hyperlink

I have a custom object with formula field using hyperlink function. However I need to create a scenario in apex test class where a formula field (using HYPERLINK formula) is click.

Example of a formula field of a custom object:

```
HYPERLINK("/00U/e?retURL=%2F006x0000001T8Om&what_id="&Id, "click me")
```

The problem is I don't know how can I simulate it in my test class.

Comment: what does the 'a formula field is click' mean?

Comment: I have a field in custom object that when click will get redirected to the URL. However, I want to create a test class where I am clicking the field URL. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

#### You can't

"Clicking" is a concept that mostly exists in the UI (User Interface) domain. Unit tests are strictly code, so you can't *actually* click anything in them. Testing UI elements and behaviors is more the realm of *functional testing*, for which you would use a tool like Selenium WebDriver (there are others, but I believe Selenium is the most well-known).

You *could* create a `PageReference` in a unit test

```java
String someId = 'some value';
PageReference pr = new PageReference('/00U/e?retURL=%2F006x0000001T8Om&what_id=' + someId);
```

But that doesn't actually follow the link. The `getContent()` method would emulate a click, but it counts as a callout and is thus not allowed to be used in unit tests (at least not without setting up a callout mock).

Since you can't get an actual response from that URL, it can't be meaningfully tested via an Apex unit test.

#### Conclusion

Use Selenium, do a manual test (i.e. set up some records, then physically click the link yourself in your browser), or simply just don't test it.

The hard-coded Opportunity Id is going to be a problem for you when you deploy this to other orgs, so you need to figure out a way to remove that from your formula.

Comment: After writing this, I thought of two other potential approaches. `Test.setCurrentPageReference()` and `ApexPages.StandardController()`. The first only helps when you're testing a controller (so you can get page parameters and such). The second doesn't allow you to set or test the `retUrl`. While it would allow you to call some methods, none would help. The `edit()` method just returns a `PageReference`, which is just a roundabout way to get back to the example PageReference already given in the body of my answer. My original conclusion still stands.